# Proving that $-|x|\leq x\leq |x|$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis

The lemma of a theorem states that $-|x| \leq x \leq |x|$.

Could someone possibly explain why this is true with a rigorous proof? It *obviously* makes sense intuitively, but I am having a difficult time seeing how to actually go about proving it in a rigorous fashion.

Answer (score 1):

For all $x\in\mathbb{R}, -|x|\leq x\leq |x|$.

*Proof*. Let $x$ be any real number. If $x\geq 0$, then
$$
-|x|=-x\leq0\leq x=|x|.
$$
If $x<0$, then 
$$
-|x|=-(-x)=x<0<-x=|x|.\quad\blacksquare
$$